# How can I get information about an uninstalled Python package?

Tags: python, command-line, version, pip, pypi

Is there an equivalent to `pip show <package>` for uninstalled packages? I am interested in the available version and dependencies before I even install the package. A similar thing can be achieved for Debian packages using

```
apt-cache show <package>
```

I know I can see this information on [CheeseShop](https://pypi.python.org/pypi) or [Crate.io](https://crate.io/), but sometimes it would be handier to be able to do this from the command line.